# google drive api export

Tags: php, google-drive-api, export, pdf-generation

I am new to google api. My goal is to upload a document (doc, docx) from a server to google drive without any client approval process. Once it is uploaded i wanted to export it as a pdf file.

I created a service account. Uploading itself works fine. Able to download the uploaded document. When i tried to export the document from the drive i am getting the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest",
        "message": "ExportonlysupportsGoogleDocs."
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "ExportonlysupportsGoogleDocs."
  }
}
```

i use the google drive api v2 php library. Here is the code i used for the export.

```
    $tempUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/xxxx/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf";
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($tempUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);

    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      $newFile = 'downLoaded.pdf';
      file_put_contents($newFile, $httpRequest->getResponseBody());
    } else {
      var_dump($httpRequest->getResponseBody());
    }
```

Is it not possible to export from google drive? What does 'ExportonlysupportsGoogleDocs.' means? What am i missing?

Thank you for your interest and any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As error message says only "Google Docs" documents can be exported. Uploaded document should have one of the mimeTypes [given here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).

For (Doc,Docx) upload with mimeType "application/vnd.google-apps.document" and try exporting as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify the Google docs [`mimeType`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#top_of_page) for them to be a Drive file.

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

And, the `400: Bad Request` means that it is `User error`. This can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

This error can be thrown when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph.

Official Documentation advice to use [`exponential backoff`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff), Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely, it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid authorization credentials or file not found errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did specify the mimeType. After several hours of work i figured out that i missed 'convert' => 'true' while uploading. This does the trick. Without this statement google does not let me export to other formats.